# twitter connectorfor multiple user configuration in mulesoft

Tags: mule

In Mulesoft, How can I manage multiple twitter user accounts dynamically because at present it requires consumerkey, consumersecret, accesskey and accesstoken in connector configuration for an application which can own only one user.

Please anyone can explain?

`<twitter:config name="Twitter__Configuration" accessKey="#[flowVars.accessToken]"  consumerKey="#[flowVars.consumerKey]"       consumerSecret="#[flowVars.consumerSecret]" doc:name="Twitter: Configuration" accessSecret="#[flowVars.accessTokenSecret]"/>
<flow name="twitterFlow1">
    <db:select config-ref="MySQL_Configuration" doc:name="Database">
        <db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[select * from twittercredentials;]]></db:parameterized-query>
    </db:select>
    <set-variable variableName="consumerKey" value="#[message.payload[0]['consumerkey']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="consumerSecret" value="#[message.payload[0]['consumersecret']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="accessToken" value="#[message.payload[0]['accesstoken']]" doc:name="Variable" />
    <set-variable variableName="accessTokenSecret" value="#[message.payload[0]['accesstokensecret']]" doc:name="Variable" />
</flow>
<flow name="twitterFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/twitterconnect" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <flow-ref name="twitterFlow1" />
    <twitter:show-user config-ref="Twitter__Configuration" doc:name="Twitter"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>`

- assigned the values in variables and accessed as flowvars in  the global element which fails.

Comment: I think you should explain better your use case. Try to elaborate what you mean by dinamically ? Give a use case or example with a flow to better explain your idea.

Comment: thanks. Trying to integrate many twitter users to my application. Twitter allows us to create one user per application with all the access token and access secret generated per application. Using twitter connector, able to assign the hard coded values each per configuration and then get the data for that twitter application. How can I do the same for multiple users using my application?How can I fetch the data for that specific data using their credentials? Or Do the Oauth get the access token and then how to use the twitter connector?

Answer (score 1):

I think in [this post](http://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/35728/twitter-connector-dynamically-configuring-access-t.html) from mule community forum you can find the answer to your question.
Basically you can use mule expression language in twitter globalk connector in this way:

```
 <twitter:config name="Twitter" accessKey="#[flowVars.accessKey]"
 accessSecret="#[flowVars.accessSecret]" consumerKey="#
[flowVars.consumerKey]" consumerSecret="#[flowVars.consumerSecret]"/>
```

Hope this helps

Full example:

This is an example flow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns:twitter="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/twitter/current/mule-twitter.xsd">
    <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <twitter:config name="Twitter" accessKey="#[flowVars['accessKey']]" accessSecret="#[flowVars['accessSecret']]" consumerKey="Cannot be parametrized" consumerSecret="Cannot be parametrized" useSSL="false"  doc:name="Twitter"/>
    <flow name="twitterFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/test" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
        <message-properties-transformer scope="invocation" doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="accessKey" value="#['myVarAccessKey']"/>
            <add-message-property key="accessSecret" value="#['myVarAccessSecret']"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <twitter:update-status config-ref="Twitter" status="ciao" doc:name="Twitter"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Here also a screenshot of a wireshark capture using IP filtering (twitter ip families) for debug the http call:

[image]

Comment: Its not working as explained. Because the connector throws an exception, Failed to connect/reconnect: Work Descriptor. Root Exception was: 401 response received, but no WWW-Authenticate header was p
 resent. Type: class java.lang.IllegalStateException. But dont know how to solve it.

Comment: Why you don't try to send the request to a localhost proxy so you can actually debug the real http request that is going out. If you need help you need to post the flow that does not work, otherwise there isn't much we can do.

Comment: edited my question with the flow. Now can you please check and help me in this. thanks

Comment: The call fails due to missing credentials ? Can you call a local http proxy or server to check the raw http request ? You can use this tool https://portswigger.net/burp/download.html for have a local proxy running and than call it instead of twitter to actually see if http request looks good.
Let me know the output.

Comment: Please also tell us Mule exact version and if you run enterprise or community edition. Thanks

Comment: using portswigger am unable to view any outbound params in the given config.<set-payload value="#[message.payload]" />
   <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="portswiggerproxyhost" port="proxyport" method="POST">
   </http:outbound-endpoint>

Comment: I am using community edition, tried using both the versions of twitter connector , having issues setting values dynamically. Mule studio vesion 5.4.1. Can someone provide the working sample for connection management pls?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the intercepted request ? or copy and past the raw content ?

Comment: What Mule CE runtime version ?

Comment: Mule 3.7 CE server version

Comment: this is the raw content I see , GET /integrations/twitterconnect HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8081
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:43.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/43.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close

Comment: Hi I just tested the twitter connector version 3.2.0 with Mule CE runtime 7.0 and I'm able to use variable in global connector and when I look at wireshark tcp traffic I can see them correctly set in the http request. Here is my config <twitter:config name="Twitter" accessKey="#[flowVars['accessKey']]" accessSecret="#[flowVars['accessSecret']]" consumerKey="cc" consumerSecret="cc" useSSL="false"  doc:name="Twitter"/>. The only difference I see is in the way I refeer to the variables in MEL but I don't think this has any effect.

Comment: Just a stupid question have you tried to hardcode variables just for test purpose without taking it from payload ? Or at least are you verifying that variables are correctly filled from db.

Comment: thanks so much for your help.yes did that. works fine with hard coded values directly in twitter config for consumer key and secret. Also, I put the logger before calling twitter function to check the value of variables. Whereas when using flow vars in config, am unsure whether the values are set in http request. am unable to see any in params via wireshark. Can you please share me the code you tested?

Comment: can we not use consumer key and secret as flow vars?

Comment: Hi, well I don't think you can also because normally you don't need to. They are specific to your APP not to the user so if the user grant access to your app than you have all you need. I will edit the question with a full example.

Comment: great. thanks. with this approach, only one user can approve the app which breaks for multi tenancy. And there is no way to authorize in twitter connector?

Comment: Not sure I Understand the question, can you provide an example?

Comment: I have a twitter app, would like to authorize as many users from my app using unique access token and get public data from them. How can I make them authorize ?  Or how to support this usecase? Though I can use the flow vars for access token and secret , but how do I get it for every user?